# What should POST request return to redirect to another page

Tags: redirect, post, header

I have a Microsoft flow, that is triggered by a POST request from one website, and I need browser to be redirected to another page on that website.
So the question is - what should that flow return (what code and headers)  for the browser to be redirected to that page?
Thanks